# Jinja 2 : escaping and extending

Tags: django-templates, jinja2, python-sphinx

I am trying to output html after running my templates through Jinja2 and thereafter through Django. The `{{ 'RAW' }}` and `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` tags are not doing what I expect then to and there is not a lot of documentation on this nor does my googling yield anything helpful.

As an example consider the following series of templates. The first is a stock Jinja2 base page which one wants to extend.

```
{# jinja_base.html #}
{% block jinja_head %}
 JINJA HEAD
{% endblock jinja_head %}
{% block jinja_body %}
 JINJA BODY
{% endblock jinja_body %}
{% block jinja_foot %}
 JINJA FOOT
{% endblock jinja_foot %}
```

The second is a stock Django template page that one wants to extend.

```
{# django_base.html #}
{% block django_head %}
 DJANGO HEAD
{% endblock django_head %}
{% block django_body %}
 DJANGO BODY
{% endblock django_body %}
{% block django_foot %}
 DJANGO FOOT
{% endblock django_foot %}
```

To extend both of them I have a Jinja/Django mixin template that reads as follows. The idea is to run it through Jinja first then through Django.

```
{# mixin.html #}
{{ '{% extends "django_base.html" %}' }}
{% extends "jinja_base.html" %}
{{ '{% block django_head %}' }}
{% block jinja_head %}
 MIXIN HEAD
{% endblock jinja_head %}
{{ '{% endblock django_head %}' }}
{{ '{% block django_body %}' }}
{% block jinja_body %}
 MIXIN BODY
{% endblock jinja_body %}
{{ '{% endblock django_body %}' }}
{{ '{% block django_foot %}' }}
{% block jinja_foot %}
 JINJA FOOT
{% endblock jinja_foot %}
{{ '{% endblock django_foot %}' }}
```

After the Jinja run, I'm expecting the following output

```
{% extends "django_base.html" %}
{% block django_head %}
 MIXIN HEAD
{% endblock django_head %}
{% block django_body %}
 MIXIN BODY
{% endblock django_body %}
{% block django_foot %}
 JINJA FOOT
{% endblock django_foot %}
```

however, I am getting the following instead.

```
{% extends "jinja_base.html" %}
 MIXIN HEAD
 MIXIN BODY
 JINJA FOOT
```

That is all the Django code which is embedded in the Jinja escape sequences is getting stripped. The first tag however is retained.

The docs mention that anything before an `extends` is kept as is but that everything after is not. There is no explanation on how best to circumvent this nor why this affects `raw`/escaped code.

Hmm.. perhaps I must place the extends right at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you extend a template you have to put the content between blocks. Every other stuff is ignored. So in the `mixin.html`:

```
{{ '{% block django_head %}' }}   <--- ignored
{% block jinja_head %}
 MIXIN HEAD
{% endblock jinja_head %}
{{ '{% endblock django_head %}' }} <--- ignored
```

The first and the last line are outside of the `jinja_head` block, thus will be ignored.

The correct way is straightforward, just put the Django lines between Jinja's blocks, e.g.:

```
{% block jinja_head %}
{{ '{% block django_head %}' }}
MIXIN HEAD
{{ '{% endblock django_head %}' }}
{% endblock jinja_head %}
```

This results:

```
{% block django_head %} 
MIXIN HEAD 
{% endblock django_head %}
```

For the `{{ '{% extends "django_base.html" %}' }}` just define an empty block in `jinja_base.html`, which you can override in the `mixin.html` with the Django extends line. The complete example:

`jinja_base.html`

```
{# jinja_base.html #}

{% block django_extends %}
{% endblock django_extends %}

{% block jinja_head %}
JINJA HEAD
{% endblock jinja_head %}

{% block jinja_body %}
JINJA BODY
{% endblock jinja_body %}

{% block jinja_foot %}
JINJA FOOT
{% endblock jinja_foot %}
```

`mixin.html`

```
{# mixin.html #}
{% extends "jinja_base.html" %}

{% block django_extends %}
{{ '{% extends "django_base.html" %}' }}
{% endblock django_extends %}

{% block jinja_head %}
{{ '{% block django_head %}' }}
MIXIN HEAD
{{ '{% endblock django_head %}' }}
{% endblock jinja_head %}

{% block jinja_body %}
{{ '{% block django_body %}' }}
 MIXIN BODY
{{ '{% endblock django_body %}' }}
{% endblock jinja_body %}

{% block jinja_foot %}
{{ '{% block django_foot %}' }}
 JINJA FOOT
{{ '{% endblock django_foot %}' }}
{% endblock jinja_foot %}
```

This way you will see the expected result after Jinja's render:

```
{% extends "django_base.html" %}

{% block django_head %}
 MIXIN HEAD
{% endblock django_head %}

{% block django_body %}
 MIXIN BODY
{% endblock django_body %}

{% block django_foot %}
 JINJA FOOT
{% endblock django_foot %}
```